# Yocto based linux (jethro) and playing fullHD video

Tags: video, omxplayer, yocto

I'm trying to play fullHD video with Rasbperry Pi model B, which uses my basic Yocto based distribution.

I have used layers `meta`, `meta-yocto`, `meta-yocto-bsp` and `meta-raspberrypi` (all from "jethro" branch) and build `rpi-test-image` with it. Unfortunately sample Big Buck Bunny 1080p video is not playing smoothly.

I tried playing the same video with Raspbian and I played smoothly (without any glitches).

In both cases I used `omxplayer` without any extra arguments.

Can you explain what is missing in Yocto based distribution?

Comment: what value did you set for GPU_MEM_512 ?

Comment: I'm not using GPU_MEM_512, only GPU_MEM which is set to 256